# How and when to check if all object values in an array are not null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with multiple dynamic input fields with different data types. I want to save the input values in state (answers) like this:

`{ [id]: value }`

Example of possible data output:

```
[
  {
    '72ebbdc4-8001-4b53-aac0': 'John doe'
  },
  {
    'dd3179c1-90bc-481c-a89e':
      '5b6d2f55-8ed0-4f76-98e69'
  },
  {
    '5acff3c7-02f8-4555-9232': 4
  },
  {
    '877817a8-6890-464b-928e': false
  },
  {
    '69e11e5a-613f-46ac-805d': []
  },
  {
    '0bb9c2f3-eda7-4e96-90f6': [
      'ad9d4c72-0972764cf9b71c42',
      'da788b55-3b68-a9c669c0ec1a'
    ]
  },
  {
    'e9c2196f-871f-25e6efb2551f': '2020-12-23'
  },
];
```

My React component is as follows. The `InputField` is a switch based on the questions type. When an input changes `updateState` is called and `this.state.answers` is updated. All of the question need to be filled in before the users can navigate to the next screen ->  `this.state.answeredAllQuestions`.

```
export default class EditComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    questions: [],
    answers: [],
    answeredAllQuestions: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fillQuestions();
  }

  // I think need a working alternative for this part
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.state.answeredAllQuestions) {
      this.checkRequiredQuestions();
    }
  }

  fillQuestions = async () => {
    const {
      response: { questions }
    } = await getQuestions();

    // Turn questions from api into answers -> [key]:value
    const answers = questions.map(el => {
      return { [el.uuid]: el.value };
    });

    this.setState({
      questions,
      answers
    });
  };

  checkRequiredQuestions = async () => {
    const { answers } = this.state;

    if (answers) {
      const values = answers.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]);

      if (
        values.every(answer => {
          (answer.required && answer !== null) || answer !== '';
        })
      ) {
        this.setState({ answeredAllQuestions: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ answeredAllQuestions: false });
      }
    }
  };

  updateState = (value, id, nestedId) => {
    const { answers } = this.state;

    if (answers) {
      // Check if answer already exists in the state, if so then replace it 
      this.setState({
        answers: this.state.answers.map(el =>
          Object.keys(el)[0] === id ? { [id]: value } : el
        )
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        answers: [{ [id]: value }]
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { questions, answers } = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={questions}
          renderItem={({ item: question }) => (
            <View key={question.id}>
              <Text>{question.label}</Text>
              <InputField
                type={question.type}
                answers={answers}
                updateState={this.updateState}
                question={question}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The big problem I have with this code is that when all input fields are filled in, the `this.state.answeredAllQuestions` is set too true. But when the user then removes a value from an input field it won't update back to false.

I don't expect someone to fix my code, but I could really use some help at the moment.

[image: Edit epic-villani-jn7gw]

Answer (score 0):

`if (values.every(answer =>
    (answer.required && (answer !== null || answer !== '' )) || answer === ''))`

If the answer is required you need to check if isn't an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by passing a `HandleInput` function to all the inputs components, that checks for every data type if true or false and puts this value in the state of the `EditComponent`.